# the designer give to me .aspx file Website without .asp.cs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

the designer give to me .aspx  file Website without .asp.cs now i can't make any change because i don't have .CS file from .ASP  can any one help me for getting .CS file by the way  i already open the file by visual studio but just .aspx without seeing the design code

Comment: Could you please elaborate us your effort showing the necessary part of the code?

Comment: So why can't you ask the designer to help you?

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click on the .aspx file is there a context menu item named "Convert to Web Application"? If so click on it and VS should generate the designer cs file for you provided the .aspx file doesn't have errors.